# If $F$ is a closed nowhere dense subset of $\mathbb{R}$, and I define $f_n(x) = \frac{1}{n}$ for $x \in F$, is $f_n(x)$ continuous?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, functional-analysis

If $F$ is a closed nowhere dense subset of $\mathbb{R}$, and I define $f_n(x) = \frac{1}{n}$ for $x \in F$, is $f_n(x)$ continuous? I am trying to prove continuity by limits but am failing:

suppose $\lim_{n \to \infty} x_n = a$, then $\lim_{n \to \infty} f(x_n) = \lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{1}{n} = 0 \neq f(a).$

Does anyone know what is going on? Thank you!

Comment: Continuous on what set? If $f_n$ is supposed to be a map from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$, then how is $f_n$ defined for $x \notin F$? Is $f_n$ zero there? If you view $f_n$ as a map from $F$ to $\mathbb{R}$, then $f$ is certainly continuous because it is constant.

Comment: I am exactly trying to prove the that it is continuous because its a constant but am having difficulty verifying it via the limit method. Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: For the limit definition at $x_0 \in F$: If $x_0$ is a limit point of $F,$ then sequential continuity at $x_0$ is immediate; and if $x_0$ is not a limit point of $F,$ then sequential continuity at $x_0$ is vacuously satisfied.